# Why is "ls /.." different to "ls /" in fakechroot fakeroot chroot environment?

Tags: chroot

I am testing a bash script.

It sometimes does this:

```
ls /..
```

In Linux, this is same as:

```
ls /
```

But in a fakechroot setup like this:

```
fakechroot fakeroot chroot sandpit
```

I get a list of files in my directory containing sandpit.

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Works for me, perhaps this was a fixed bug

Comment: Agreed. It works as I had initially expected now. Thanks for update.